# nproc produce results inconsistent with hardware report

Tags: bash, cpu

I check the manual to count cpu

```
DESCRIPTION
       Print  the  number of processing units available to the current process, which may be less than
       the number of online processors
```

it output

```
$ nproc
4
```

When I check the hardware setting, it report:

```
Number of Processors:   1
Total Number of Cores:  2
```

nproc produce a result which 4 times cpu and 2 times cores.

I get the jargon physical and virtual to explain,
but I confused why not 3 or 8?

Comment: It is likely that you have: one processor, meaning on physical integrated circuit chip; On that chip, you have 2 cores, each with two threads. for a total of 4 CPUs. However, I am guessing. Do `cat /proc/cpuinfo` to know for sure.

Comment: thank you. in python, Thread.start() is to start a new thread in parallel, that Thread is this thread in cores? @DougSmythies

Comment: No, process threads are a different thing. You can hundreds, even thousands, of process threads.

Comment: yes, sort of confused, and I do search jobs. Could you please transmit your first comment to answer. @DougSmythies

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is likely that you have: one processor, meaning one physical integrated circuit chip; On that chip, you have 2 cores, each with two threads, for a total of 4 CPUs.